# Oracle 9i: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle9i, oracle.manageddataaccess

I get the following exception when I try to connect to my Oracle 9i database from my Visual Studio 2017 application:

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Code:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myServerName)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=mySID)));User Id = myUsername; Password = myPassword";
var con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();
```

Same problem when :

- using same code with `System.Data.OracleClient` assembly
- trying to add a new Data Connection via Server Explorer in Visual Studio.

I tried setting `System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy\Enabled to` `0` with no luck.

When I use SQL Developer I am able to connect to the same database with same credentials and perform any query.
Any idea ?

Database: Oracle 9i

Visual Studio : 2017

Comment: Remove the spaces between the parameter name and the parameter value. It probably would try to send "[space]myUsername" and "[space]myPassword"

Comment: I removed spaces, still same error message

Comment: you are using Oracle.DataAccess.Client? the same basic settings work for me -- string connectionString = "Data Source=//myhost/myservice; User Id=scott; Password=tiger"

Comment: Yes, I am referencing the oracle.dataaccess.dll in my project

Comment: Check to see that no unintentional case conversion is going on.  Passwords are case-sensitive in more recent versions of Oracle.

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald Oracle 9i is not case-sensitive (starting from 11), anyway both username and password are written te same way I use (with success) on SQL Developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

- remove any associated plugin in Visual Studio
- execute uninstall.bat from your ODAC downloaded folder
- remove any associated tool in Windows Add or Remove Program
- Remove remaining Oracle folders (in C:\, C:\ProgramFiles, ...)

Make sure there is no remaining Oracle reference in GAC, otherwise delete them.

The latest compatible version of Oracle provider is Oracle version + 2 (9+2=11), meaning the maximum version I had to install was 11.2.0.4. After installing this version and compile my code in x64 (Any CPU or x32 won't load the DLL) evrything was working.